# Textbox should be visible if corresponding checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, textbox, checkbox

I have a list of textboxes and checkboxes corresponding to it. I want to make only those textboxes visible whose checkboxes have been checked by the user. How can I do this?

```
<input type="text" name="album_text[]" id="album_text" class="album_text"  />
<input type="text" name="album_text[]" id="album_text" class="album_text"   />
<input type="text" name="album_text[]" id="album_text" class="album_text"  />

<input name="album_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="album_checkbox" value="' . $res. '">
<input name="album_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="album_checkbox" value="' . $res. '">
<input name="album_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="album_checkbox" value="' . $res. '">
```

Right now, on the click of the update button, all textboxes become visible regardless of the checkbox:

```
$("#album_edit").click(function() {


                    $(".album_text").show();



        });
```

**EDIT:** The texboxes and the checkboxes are generated dynamically at runtime.

Comment: First problem i would say is that you are using same `ID` for multiple objects. Which should be unique! If you like, you can use .eq() property so if text input.eq(0) is clicked checkbox input.eq(0) would be visible.

Comment: Even if they are, example i provided below, would work! But on reading ur que again, i might have swapped text input fields and checkboxes but you can just change the classes and should work the other way around!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's working example, http://jsfiddle.net/JmqLH/

HTML:

```
<span class='textinput'>
    <input type="text" name="album_text[]" id="album_text1" class="album_text"  />
    <input type="text" name="album_text[]" id="album_text2" class="album_text"   />
    <input type="text" name="album_text[]" id="album_tex3t" class="album_text"  />
</span>    <br>
<span class='chkbx'>
    <input name="album_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="album_checkbox1" value="' . $res. '">
    <input name="album_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="album_checkbox2" value="' . $res. '">
    <input name="album_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="album_checkbox3" value="' . $res. '">
</span>
```

JS:

```
$('span.chkbx input').hide();

$('.album_text').click(function(){
    var indexme = $(this).prevAll().length;
    $('.chkbx input').eq(indexme).show();
});
```

Update 1: http://jsfiddle.net/JmqLH/1/

Update 2: http://jsfiddle.net/JmqLH/2/ Swapped the two input types in JS...

Update 3: http://jsfiddle.net/JmqLH/3/ Swapped the two input groups in HTML...

Comment: the textboxes and checboxes are generated at runtime.

Comment: @tunharyyaaden, this should ideally work but it isn't working somehow. I want to show the textboxes when the user has checked the checkboxes of the data he wants to update and clicks the EDIT button.

Comment: @fuz3d: check third update http://jsfiddle.net/JmqLH/3/ i swapped the locations of the two groups

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use the same `id` for multiple elements. You can use a `class` selector instead. You can then assign corresponding `id`s like `album_text_1` and `album_checkbox_1`, which will make the next step less error-prone.

Second, you should check if the checkbox is `checked`:

```
var checkboxes = $('.album_checkbox'),
    textFields = $('.album_text');

checkboxes.change(function() {
    // Eg. replace album_checkbox_1 with album_text_1
    var textField = $('#' + this.id.replace(/^_checkbox_/, '_text_'));
    if(this.checked) {
        textField.show();
    } else {
        textField.hide();
    }
});
```

If you can't use unique `id`s (you don't have control over the markup), you can use `.index()` and `.eq()` instead, only if you are sure that the order of each set of elements matches up. So it would be similar code to the above, but replacing line 6 with:

```
var textField = textFields.eq(checkboxes.index(this));
```

Comment: the texboxes and the checkboxes are generated dynamically at runtime, so I cannot give unique IDs to them. I tried using `eq` and `index` and changed `id` to `class` but nothing happens. No textboxes show up.

Comment: i added an auto-increment dyanmically to the foreach loop to the textbox and checkbox, and changed line 6 to the one as you had posted originally, yet nothing happens. It does not even throw any error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they will, because all of them have the same id and class..so when you are $(".album_text"), all the textboxes will pass and will be shown. You need to find a mechanism to tie/identify the textboxes uniquely to the checkbox and then use that unique id/class in your jquery code to display the textbox.